# Getting the decimal part of a double variable and convert it to char array?

Tags: c++, double, precision

I'm doing a little library to be able to do operations with really big numbers, and now I'm trying to implement the decimal part of them.

To generate said numbers, I need a double number to translate it into a char array. The integer part is done, but the decimal part is what is making me struggle.

Take a look at this program:

```
double a = 123.123456;
double dec = a - int(a);

while (dec) {
    dec *= 10;
    cout << int(dec);  // Here it just outputs the decimal digit for the sake of simplicity.
    dec -= int(dec);
}
```

At first, I thought "Okay, this will do it", but the output, instead of being `123456` it is `123456000000004451067070476710796356201171875`.

I'm almost sure that this is because of the precision of the double numbers, but I **really** want to get the `123456` part.

This problem is even more difficult when I add more decimals to the first number, because the "real" digits intersect with the "non-real" ones.

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

When the double number has a decimal part of 0 (like 123. or 123.0 or 123.00000000), there is no garbage digits.

Comment: Why not just use GMP - https://gmplib.org - if you want to work with "really big numbers", instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The output is ok (what the double really represents). The only exact decimals in a binary floating point number are 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, ... and the combinations

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because I'm mastering C++ and I want to do things by myself. Little problems like this are gold for me.

Comment: Read these (amongst others): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html , https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point - floating point math is *not* exact.

Comment: @DieterLücking That actually makes A LOT of sense.

Comment: Use `<cmath>` and the `modf()` function — not to be confused with the `fmod()` function — to get the integer and fractional parts separately.  Then format the fraction as you wish.